# Como marcar y desmarcar todos los checkbox a la vez pulsando un boton

Tags: php, javascript, html

Necesito esta funcion podrian ayudarme.
Desde ya muchas gracias.
Este es mi codigo:

```
include('conexion.php');
include('bloquedeseguridad.php');
$query="SELECT identificacion as cedula, id as id , nombre as nombre, telone as telefono, teltwo as daviplata, calificacion as grupo FROM `vw_usupreaprobados`  ORDER BY `vw_usupreaprobados`.id ASC";
$datos= null;
$datos = mysql_query($query);
?>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="administrarcreditos.php">Administrar creditos</a>
    <a href="enviarPrimerMensaje.php">Enviar mensaje</a>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="button"><a href="salir.php">Salir</a></button>
<p style="text-align: center;">Enviar Mensaje</p>
<button type="button" id="button">>Seleccionar todo</button>
<br><br>
<center>
   <hr>
   <?php if ($datos) {   ?>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>       </th>
  <th>Cédula</th>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th>Telefeno</th>
  <th>Telefono Daviplata</th>
   <th>Grupo</th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <?php  while ($registro=mysql_fetch_assoc($datos)) {?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $registro['id'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $registro['cedula']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $registro['nombre']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $registro['telefono']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $registro['daviplata']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $registro['grupo']; ?></td>
  <td>
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="actualizar(this.id)" value="first_checkbox" id="<?php echo $registro['id'] ?>"><br>
</td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
</table>
<?php   } else{?>
   <p> No hay información </p>
   <?php } ?>
   <hr>
</center>
<input type="button" id="boton" value="Enviar" onclick="enviarMensaje()">
```

Comment: escribe el codigo que tienes para ayudarte mejor

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre tu inquietud te dejo un enlace relacionado:

## Html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="setting-1" class="settings" />
<input type="checkbox" id="setting-2" class="settings" />
<input type="checkbox" id="setting-3" class="settings" />
<input type="checkbox" id="setting-4" class="settings" />
<input type="checkbox" id="setting-5" class="settings" />

<button class="check-all">Check All</button>
```

## JS

```
var checked = false;

$('.check-all').on('click',function(){

if(checked == false) {
$('.settings').prop('checked', true);
checked = true;
} else {
$('.settings').prop('checked', false);
checked = false;
}

});
```

By https://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/qOrYbN

Lo que requieres hacer es manipular las propiedades desde jquery del html, lo haces desde el DOM, y por tanto requieres trabajar con los eventos de los input, en este caso particular con el onclick y generar un distintivo grupal a los input que requieres agrupar, para esto puedes usar clases y si requieres posteriormente iterar seria tmb con jquery con .each para obtener los id's de cada chexbox. Saludos.